# Is it possible to mine with core duo cpu 2.4 ghz?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-profitability

My PC details:

Processor:             Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T8300 @ 2.4GHz 2.4GHz
Installed Memory(RAM): 4GB DRAM
Video Card GPU: Mobile Intel(R) 965 Express Chipset Family

Could you please tell me what is the fastest btc miner I can use?

Thank you in advance
Joseph Omondi Odhiambo

Answer (score 6):

Mine Bitcoin? Absolutely not.

At current difficulty you'd need almost 16 million years to mine a block.

The only profitable mining operations are using what are called ASICs (Application Specific Integrated Circuits). These devices use the SHA256 hash algorithm starting at 1Ghash/sec (compared to maybe 50000-100000 hash/sec on a CPU. Not kHash, but hash.

Some "Altcoins" utilise algorithms less amendable   To ASICs but still require high end GPU video cards. Even the Scrypt algorithm Litecoin uses is mined by ASICs now. There are algorithms which can be mined by CPU like Scrypt-n but even these use CPU/GPU combination mining I believe.